# Is UDK the same as UE4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

I want to start on learning to develop games using Unreal Engine. I have found tutorials but they all use UDK, and since I am using Mac OS X, I can't have UDK but instead UE4.

My question is, is UDK and UE4 similar with UE4 being improved, and can I watch UDK videos and apply on UE4?

Answer (score 3):

UDK was what they called the SDK for Unreal Engine 3.

Unreal Engine 4 doesn't use the UDK name anymore, likely because it's not just an SDK that is available for most-people anymore, it's the entire engine.

> My question is, is UDK and UE4 similar with UE4 being improved, and can I watch UDK videos and apply on UE4?

UE4 is a pretty significant change from UDK/UE3. Some aspects and concepts from UDK may be applicable, but you are probably better off using UE4 resources to get started. Epic has and continues to release a substantial amount of resource through [their website](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/index.html), and [their YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/UnrealDevelopmentKit). There is also loads of 3rd-party resources out there.

Comment: I have seen the resources provided by Unreal themselves, but couldn't find 3rd-party resources. Can you please provide me with them, whether video or books. Thanks!

Comment: @coding4fun I haven't gotten to work with UE4 as much, so I can't make too many recommendations. Epic has [a Wiki page](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Category:Tutorials) for community tutorials. I believe Digital-Tutors released some UE4 tutorials if you have access to or are will to pay for them. I would definitely start with Epic's getting started guides though, before using other resources.

Comment: Udemy have some decent training tutorials

Answer (score 0):

UDK was made from UnrealEngine 3 which required permitting and UDK didn't. This was in 2009. I envision that UE4 is presumably much further [kroger feedback](https://kroger-feedback-survey.com) developed than the UDK now 
UDK was what they called the SDK for Unreal Engine 3.